# Cannot upload iOS simulator build for Facebook App review

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I literally cannot upload iOS simulator build for Facebook App review.

I have an iOS universal (iPhone/iPad) video game that I need to submit to Facebook review in order to get approval for "publish_actions" permission.

I've successfully built the iOS simulator build, compressed it to a ZIP archive and then it simply doesn't get uploaded to the corresponding Facebook web site form.

What I've already tried:

- I've tried to upload different versions of my app - one is 216MB
  compressed, the other is 360MB. *Could it be the size of the archive

  that is too big?*
- I've tried to use different archive programs to make the ZIP
  archive.
- I've tried to upload it from different browsers (Safari, Chrome)
  and platforms (Mac OS X, Windows 7).

No success at all.

I do the following steps:

- Click the "provide a version" link
- Click the "Use an Uploaded Simulator Build" button
- Click the "Choose a File" button
- Select the ZIP archive with the app
- Then I see a spinning progress bar

And then - **nothing** happens.

**UPDATE:**

I've additionally tried the following things as advised:

- Created a new empty application. Did a simulator build. And **successfully** uploaded it. Size of the archive was 23KB
- Enabled network state logging in dev tools of Chrome, Safari, Firefox and indeed there's **no sign of data transfer** when uploading my application archive

**UPDATE 2:**

I've filed a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/487303678067797) to facebook

They know about this issue.

Comment: Have you had this issue resolved yet? I have the same problem and can't find any answers

Answer (score 0):

Most internet connections have much crappier upload speed than download speed. Uploading 200MB would really take a long while. How much did you wait?

Try making an empty new project and uploading a build of it to see if it goes up.
Try checking your network activity while you're waiting to see if you're really uploading anything.

Comment: I've updated my question with actions you've suggested. Any other ideas? It rather seems to me that size of the archive is the reason. But don't see for myself any reasonable solution to shrink it down.

Answer (score 0):

File a bug @ developers.facebook.com . Facebook support will help you figure out the issue much faster.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/